# PowerShell access denied for deleting file/folder

Tags: powershell, access-denied

I have a script in PowerShell where I collect old log files, create a zip archive from each file, then delete the original file. Same script is doing folder compression and files compression separately.

While running my script, the files are getting compressed successfully, but when trying to delete the source file I get an access denied error. If I try and delete the file manually in Windows explorer, it gets deleted with no issues.
Most of the files are getting deleted successfully but just for some I get that error.

To delete I use the following command:
get-childitem -Path "mypath" | Remove-item

Tried using -Force and it's still the same.
How can I get around that "access denied" error?

Comment: Include your code please. What do you use to zip the files? The process might still have locks on the files you try to delete.

Comment: Maybe the files are still used by a process.

Comment: You are not specifying `-File` to Get-ChildItem. Perhaps now it is trying to remove a non-empty folder aswell leading to that error?

Comment: What happens if you put start-sleep 20 before you delete files?  Sometimes an anti-virus is locking the files.

Comment: Please edit your question and make it clear if you want to [1] delete files only [2] files **and** folders [3] if you need to remove the items recursively (include files/folders in subfolders) or not.